# Devexpress aspxgridview - master - detail - runtime binding, detail grid cant be found

Tags: devexpress, aspxgridview, master-detail

So I create plop two gridviews onto page, define BOTH their datasources in code behind :

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DataTable dt = Common_Users.GetUsersDataTable();
            gvMaster.DataSource = dt;
            gvMaster.DataBind();
            gvDetail.DataSource = dt;
            gvDetail.DataBind();
        }
```

Then tell the Master gv to use a details row and I open the detailsRow template and (as devexpress says to do) I put the DETAIL gv inside that template.

However, NOW my page_load can no longer fine gvDetail ... How do I continue to call gvDetail NOW that its inside of gvMaster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is necessary to provide data for detail ASPxGridView by handling its **BeforePerformDataSelect** event. Check the http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/e/E257.aspx example to see this approach in action.